# How do I search for documentation on numerical macros?

Tags: objective-c, c, math

I know there are objective-c (or C) macros for quantities like maximum integer, max float, max unsigned integer, etc. but every time I need to use one I can't remember it and I can't find it by searching. How do you search for those things?

Comment: You know you can ⌘+Click on any symbol to get its definition or declaration in Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Google [limits.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html).
- Even better, look up this file on your system.
- Then, in Xcode (and other IDEs) code-completion is your friend; just start to type "int" and you'll see the list: `INT16_MAX`, `INT16_MIN`, ...  On Xcode (in iOS project) I did not have to explicitly `#include <limit.h>` but you may have to do this first on other IDEs.